# ACF: How can I publish values of ACF fields in a loop while using wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF to add fields to a custom post type.

I've created an instance of WP_Query to set up a loop.
Within the loop I can publish the standard fields using the_title() and the_content().
However, the ACF function the_field isn't publishing values for attached fields.

Neither 'the_field()' nor 'echo the_field()' products the field values.

So... how exactly can I publish these values?

This is my loop:

```
$jobs_query = new WP_Query($args) ;


if ($jobs_query->have_posts()) : ?>
    <section id="jobs-list">
        <?php while ($jobs_query->have_posts()) : $jobs_query->the_post(); ?>
            <article class="">
                
                <h3 class="job-title"><?php the_title()  ?></h3>

        <div class="employer">
            <p><?php  the_field('employer')  ?></p>         
        </div>

        
        <div class="job-description">
            <?php echo  the_field('job_description')  ?>
        </div>
        
        
                <p class="job-readmore"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink()  ?>">read more</a></p>
        
            </article>
        <?php endwhile; ?>


    <h4>done</h4>
    
    </section>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$PostID = get_the_ID();
the_field('text_field', $PostID);
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?